# interchanging values after comparing two columns in R

Tags: r

i want to write a code that checks two columns in a dataframe and compares them. one is supposed to have lower limit and the other upper limits. if values on the upper limit columns are less than on the lower limit, them it should interchange the values. if both lower and upper limits are zero, it should replace the upper limit column with a value say 2. a sample data is as below:

```
lower_limit upper_limit
0   3
0   4
5   2
0   15
0   0
0   0
7   4
8   2
```

after running the code, it should produce something like

```
lower_limit upper_limit
0   3
0   4
2   5
0   15
0   2
0   2
4   7
2   8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `dat` is the name of your data frame/matrix:

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) { 
                                         tmp <- sort(x);
                                         tmp[2] <- tmp[2] + (!any(x)) * 2; 
                                         return(tmp) }))), colnames(dat))
  lower_limit upper_limit
1           0           3
2           0           4
3           2           5
4           0          15
5           0           2
6           0           2
7           4           7
8           2           8
```

*How it works?*

The function `apply` is used to apply a function to each line (argument `1`). In this function, `x` represents a line of `dat`. Firstly, the values are ordered (with `sort`) and stored in the object `tmp`. Then, the second value of `tmp` is replaced with `2` if both values are `0`. Finally, `tmp` is returned. The function `apply` returns the results as matrix, which needs to be transposed (with `t`). This matrix is transformed to a data frame (`as.data.frame`) with the same column names as the original object `dat` (with `setNames`).

Comment: am trying to understand what your function is doing, can you explain a bit please.

Comment: @jonestats I added an explanation.

Comment: Have seen it, Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have 16 datasets with similar column names and would like to replace the upper and lower values in all the them, is it possible to use a loop to do this?

Comment: @jonestats You should create a new question with example data. I suppose you could use `lapply` together with the function in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
dfrm <- read.table(text="lower_limit upper_limit
 0   3
 0   4
 5   2
 0   15
 0   0
 0   0
 7   4
 8   2", header=TRUE)

dfrm2 <- dfrm
 dfrm2[,2] <- pmax(dfrm[,1], dfrm[,2] )
 dfrm2[,1] <- pmin(dfrm[,1], dfrm[,2] );
dfrm2[abs(pmax(dfrm[,1],dfrm[,2]))==0 , 2] <- 2

> dfrm2
  lower_limit upper_limit
1           0           3
2           0           4
3           2           5
4           0          15
5           0           2
6           0           2
7           4           7
8           2           8
```

Comment: obviously nice and clean but I think rows 5 and 6 should be a 2 for `upper_limit`.

Comment: @DWin but this answers only first part of the question:)

Comment: Yeah. Noticed that. Fixed.

Comment: DWin, am using your code and it does not replace 2 when both columns are zero

Comment: It (still) works for me after starting a fresh session. Adding the code to create a reproducible version of `dfrm`.